# Find Python Source Filename After os.chdir()

Tags: python, python-unittest

I've got a pyunit test that does an `os.chdir()` to go to a temporary test directory.  I'd like to reach back and grab a file that is next to the python script being executed.

`inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())` returns the filename for the executing file.  But I cannot find the associated directory.

`os.path.dirname.os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))` returns the path to `os.getcwd()` with the filename appended, but I cannot find a way to get the full path to the running script.

I've checked all the duplicates that this kind of questions get sent to and have found no solution to this scenario, which is changing to a new temporary directory and trying to reach back and copy a file next to the original script.

I would do the copy before, but I'm extending a TestCase that puts me into the temporary directory before my test starts running.  So my only link back is the executing file.

Comment: I don't think python stores any absolute paths. It's usually not a problem, because it's really your own fault if you change the current working directory regardless of the fact that your code can't handle that. I see two options here: 1) Store the absolute path to the script immediately when the program starts. 2) Don't change the cwd.

Comment: I was just heading down the path of storing the absolute path in the parent class for the children to use.  I'm surprised that there are no absolute paths available.

Comment: D'oh! And now I see I already did this in `self.previous_dir`.  Past Ray is much smarter than current Ray.

Comment: Again: don't use `chdir`.

Comment: I think you have to do to what I want, run a test in a temporary directory then delete all the detritus.

Comment: The path to the running script is stored in `__file__`

Comment: As far as I can see it's just the filename.